# ubuntu: server management GUI tools like ebox?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration-management

i wonder if there are some GUI management tools for ubuntu to be used to manage all server tasks.

eg. installing server applications, managing them, editing their conf files and so on.

i saw ebox and i thought it was something i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/). This is not only for Ubuntu but works like the ebox web interface.

Comment: looks very promising. but if i want to edit a certain service's config files directly, could i do this with webmin's web interface or do i have to use vim/vi in ssh in the traditional way? cause i still want to have the flexibility to add more precise rules.

Comment: This will depend on the Webmin module. In many cases the module itself gives you an opportunity to provide custom settings, or respects any customs changes you make (via vim/vi). However if you are going to make custom changes you need to test this, as some modules will blow away custom configuration settings.

Answer (score 1):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) provides a "webish" interface, but it also has a SSH module, which in turn launches a Java app in your browser to connect to the server in question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, compared to Webmin you may find eBox is a better fit for what you want to do. The nice thing about eBox is that it takes a more abstract approach and handles the configuration of multiple services at the same time. In contrast Webmin is service specific, so if you have a task that touches on two or three services it can be time consuming to perform.

It also depends on what services you want to configure. eBox covers the main bases, but when it comes to flexibility and extensibility Webmin wins hands down.

Another factor is how much you want to learn about each service. eBox abstracts the complexity away from you so that you do not need to understand the nuts and bolts. In contrast the majority of Webmin's modules are simply providing a GUI editor for configuration files. As a consequence you need to have a good understanding of the underlying services if you wish to achieve anything meaningful with Webmin.

Finally, you may want to install my Webmin theme:
http://www.stress-free.co.nz/webmin-theme

It tidies up the UI and adds a module search box which will help you get started if you choose to take the Webmin route. Whilst I've spent quite a bit of time putting the theme together, I've found that a combination of command line, Webmin and eBox works best depending on the situation.